# Tabular View option not showing while modifying or creating view Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, document

Tabular View option is not showing while modifying or creating view SharePoint 2010.

I want to show checkboxes but tabular view option not showing. I have done changing the tabular view to default and then tabular as this solution works for some people but not for me.

[image: Image is attached for what it is showing to me.]

Answer (score 0):

If tabular view option is not available from UI. You can try setting it using Power Shell. Following is the sample code:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb 'siteUrl'
$spList = $spWeb.Lists['ListName']
$spView = $spList.Views["View_Name"]
$spView.TabularView = $true
$spView.Update()
```

Comment: I tried your given code , it fetches view but after that it gives error. ( Given Below )
Property TabularView cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable. 
Property Not found.

Comment: Normally it should be available. Perhaps the view is corrupt. Did you try checking tabular view on any other test list in your site?

Comment: Yes This option is available in other lists and document library but not showing in picture library. else is all good. 
i also create a new view but this option is not showing. i also created a new Picture library this option is not showing in new picture library too.